# Android Studio: Rendering Library more recent than version of Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

[image]

I am trying to browse a pre-made program and while i can access some parts of it such as the stored pictures in the resource folder i cannot see the .xml because my rendering library is more recent than my version Android Studio. Note that I literally just reinstalled Studio with the instructions and all including how to install ubuntu make then installing android from that on this website:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make

I have the most recent stable version of studio which is 1.2. I checked for updates and it said I had the most recent update. What do i need to do to stop this error and move on? Do i need to downgrade my rendering library? (i wouldnt happen to know how to do that either)

Does it matter that the program was made in Eclipse and I imported it as a non studio file and had it converted for use in studio?

Comment: Can I download the project to test it?

Comment: here it is ---> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18586857/udemy/lbd-android-beginners/Traffic%20Lights.zip

Comment: @A.B. that's the unconverted file

Comment: @A.B. I just got it and posted the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh... After a bit of messing around I found what was wrong:

[image]

It was the API version that was giving me the error. I just kept clicking around until it showed none!